# dynamically create thumbnail on client machine with javascript

Tags: javascript, image, gallery, thumbnails, exif

I'm working on photo gallery. Using php to read files and pushing it to jquery on client machine to build image gallery. (works good)

I wanted to use php exif function to get thumbnails of images to make preview of photos

I cannot use php function since my hosting disabled exif module.

I found great library [php library](http://www.ozhiker.com/electronics/pjmt/library/Example.php?jpeg_fname=test.jpg) but i cannot start it to use as i want it to. I just cannot find good manual for this. (ill continue to work on this, because this work on test image)

i dont wont to use crop like functions (jquery or html) for this, since i dont want to download all images right from the start. I want only to load thumbnails and on click this will load the image itself.

Can anyone please help me with this? 
Thank a lot!!!!

Alexei
alexela.biz

Comment: You'll have to download the image before you can do the transformation.

Comment: If someone interesting i made small gallery that uses nailthumb plugin 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13821941/addclass-then-removeclass-on-click-jquery/13825691#13825691

will post final version tomorrow. need to make page+ page- function. 
Hope it useful.
alexei

Answer (score 1):

Did your host disable [GD and image](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php) functions?

Try this block:  http://davidwalsh.name/create-image-thumbnail-php

Comment: Only EXIF module is disabled. and they will not set it up. PHP works great. But only on localhost. when i put it to the server i'm getting error. I spoke to techsupp they told me same thing. module is disabled.

Comment: Getting a new web host is easier than alternatives.

Comment: )))) like this one.
I'm searching for new one. Not because of this, but of the slow performance (arvixe) in my country. But until i'll find, i need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to download the image to the browser if you want to tranform it there. So just set the style of the image so the browser displays it as a thumb.

For example if your image is 460 x 460px then you could create a 100x100 px thumb by adding the following style to the img tag.

```
<img id="my_thumb" src="my/image/source460x460.jpg" style="height: 100px, width: 100px">
```

I guess your javascript would look something like -

```
var imageElement = document.getElementById('my_thumb');
```

Standards based browsers

```
imageElement.setAttribute('style', "height: 100px, width: 100px");
```

Dodgy IE browser

```
imageElement.style.setAttribute('cssText', "height: 100px, width: 100px");
```

and jquery

```
$('#my_thumb').attr('style') = "height: 100px, width: 100px";
```

Comment: You right, i can use it. But as i wrote, i dont want to. 
main thing i dont want to load all images from the beginning. if ill use such method, it will happen.

Comment: Sorry I read the question title and figured you must already have the image at the client (I'm pretty sure you'll need the original image at the client if you're going to do the transformation there)

Comment: user1873689, you'd already have to download the images to the client to make thumbs out of them. In that event, you might as well simply use a down-sized image for the thumb, as Aidan Ewen suggested.

Comment: I got only filenames at client size first. so i think you right. i cannot only use thumbs in files itself.

Comment: Ill have to write my own image script (using php script i found (it works great)) or make simple downgrade-size thumbs.

Comment: May be some one have php script that not uses exif_thumbnail() function??? (script i posted works) ????
Thanks a lot

Comment: I used nailthumb plug in.
If anyone interested - http://www.garralab.com/nailthumb.php
With loading image. 
It's not exactly that i wanted but for now its good