# addClass() then removeClass() on click (jquery)

Tags: jquery, click, addclass, removeclass

.I'm trying to make some gallery.
Want to use addClass to show image and then click on same place to remove this new class
I googled for help, but after hour of trying to get it work normally, i'm asking you for help.
I found here solution for reversed option (first remove and add)

Code:

```
<html>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.s-ola.me/js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.s-ola.me/js/jquery.nailthumb.1.1.min.js"></script>
<style>

#window {
width:              570px;
height:             455px;
position:           relative;
background-color:   grey;
padding:            20px;
margin:             0 auto;
top:                50%;
margin-top:         -225px;
}

.image {
display:    inline-block;
margin:     5px;
}

 #wrapper {
width:              568px;
height:             455px;
position:           absolute;
}

.close {
display:    none;
}
.big_image{
width:      100%;
display:    block;
}
</style>
<body>

<div id="window">
<div id="wrapper">
    <img class="image" src="http://www.livethelesson.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/snow.jpg" />
    <img class="image" src="http://www.livethelesson.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/snow.jpg" />
    <img class="image" src="http://www.livethelesson.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/snow.jpg" />
    <img class="image" src="http://www.livethelesson.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/snow.jpg" />
    <img class="image" src="http://www.livethelesson.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/snow.jpg" />
    <img class="image" src="http://www.livethelesson.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/snow.jpg" />
    <img class="image" src="http://www.livethelesson.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/snow.jpg" />
    <img class="image" src="http://www.livethelesson.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/snow.jpg" />
    <img class="image" src="http://www.livethelesson.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/snow.jpg" />
    <img class="image" src="http://www.livethelesson.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/snow.jpg" />
    <img class="image" src="http://www.livethelesson.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/snow.jpg" />
    <img class="image" src="http://www.livethelesson.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/snow.jpg" />
    <img class="image" src="http://www.livethelesson.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/snow.jpg" />
    <img class="image" src="http://www.livethelesson.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/snow.jpg" />
    <img class="image" src="http://www.livethelesson.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/snow.jpg" />
    <img class="image" src="http://www.livethelesson.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/snow.jpg" />
    <img class="image" src="http://www.livethelesson.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/snow.jpg" />
    <img class="image" src="http://www.livethelesson.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/snow.jpg" />
    <img class="image" src="http://www.livethelesson.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/snow.jpg" />
    <img class="image" src="http://www.livethelesson.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/snow.jpg" />
</div>
</div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$('.image').nailthumb({containerClass:'image',height:100, width:100, fitDirection:'center', proportions:0.5, maxShrink:0.5});
})

$(document).ready(function(){

$('img').click(function(){
    $('.image').toggleClass('close');
    $('#wrapper').append('<img src="'+this.src+'" class="big_image" />');
})

})
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.big_image').click(function(){
    if($('.big_image')) {$('.big_image').remove(); $('.image').toggleClass('close'); }
})

})

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please let me know where i mistaken.

Thanks again.
Alexei
alexela.biz

---

Updated

Comment: looks like that when it add new image on top it not using     $(document).ready(function(){
 $('img').click(function(){
anymore

Comment: made change: 
can anyone please tell me why it's not working?

    $(document).ready(function(){
 $('img').click(function(){
  if (document.getElementsByClassName('big_image')) {
   $('.image').addClass('close');
   $('#wrapper').append('<img class="big_image" src="'+this.src+'" />');
  }
  else
  {
   $('.big_image').remove();
   $('.image').removeClass('close');
  }
 })
    })

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally made it
Here is my solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('img.image, img.big_image').live('click', function(){
    if (!$('.big_image').length) {
        $('.image').addClass('close');
        $('#wrapper').append('<img class="big_image" src="'+this.src+'" />');
    }
    else
    {
        $('.image').removeClass('close');
        $('.big_image').remove();
    }
})
})
```

hope it will help

Comment: Made an update - $('img.image, img.big_image').live('click', function(){
otherwise it works on anyimages you click.
Hope this will help. 
I'll put finished ver on finish.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('#wrapper').toggleClass('close');
```

This will add a close class when it is not there and removes the class when it's there

Answer (score 1):

```
 if($('#wrapper').hasClass('close')) {$('#wrapper').removeClass('class')}
```

You probably mean:

```
 if($('#wrapper').hasClass('close')) {$('#wrapper').removeClass('close')}
```

Comment: You check for the existence of class "close" then you remove class "class".  You probably meant to write "close" there.